# http request response is very slow in hybrid app

Tags: android, ajax, http, cordova

I am working on Hybrid App with Phonegap. 
For getting and Putting request to database i have to use HTTP request response through Ajax.

But HTTP request/response process is very very slow in hybrid app.

I just want to know, how can i make http request/response faster to make my app run fast?

Thanks

Deepak Ratra

Comment: Have you done profiling or debugging to see _what_ actually takes the time? Is it the server? The communication? If it's hard for you to know, it's even harder for everyone here that has not even seen the code and don't have a chance to debug.

Comment: yes, sever is taking to long to respond.

Comment: Then you're most likely stuck with optimising the server. Nothing you can do in cordova will speed up a slow server response.

Answer (score 0):

First you post the request url from your browser. See , how it is responding. If it is slow in browser, some thing issue with your server itself. You need to fix that first.

Comment: i checked, it is fast in browser but slower in Application.